# Access getter methods on a superclass via lldb - Expected getter method not found on object

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, lldb

I have this property:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *dismissKeyboardButton;
```

and a break point after this line:

```
self.dismissKeyboardButton.hidden = NO;
```

Code has halted after this break point. In the lldb console I check the button using:

```
(lldb) po self.dismissKeyboardButton
$2 = 0x0966b240 <UIButton: 0x966b240; frame = (431 234; 49 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x966b300>>
```

However, I can't check a property on its UIView superclass, e.g.

```
(lldb) po self.dismissKeyboardButton.hidden
error: expected getter method not found on object of type 'UIButton *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Can you access getter methods on a superclass via lldb and, if so, how?

Comment: `p ((UIView *)self.dismissKeyboardButton).hidden`, is it that?

Comment: (lldb) p ((UIView *)self.dismissKeyboardButton).hidden  
error: expected getter method not found on object of type 'UIView *'  
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: "Go home LLDB, you're drunk"...

Comment: because the getter's name is actually `isHidden`

Comment: @justin doh! well spotted.